# OpneMP segmentation fault using reduction on a big array

Tags: c++, openmp

I've a problem with OpenMP. I'm trying to parallelize the first step of the Counting Sort algorithm: counting the frequencies of all the possibile values (in this case I'm counting the number of neighbors of all vertices of a graph).
When I run this code on a small array (e.g. num_vertices = 100k) it works fine. Instead, when the row_ptr array is big (e.g. num_vertices = 1M) i get segmentation fault (or sometimes zsh: bus error).

PS: it works fine also with high number of iteration (e.g. num_edges = 50M) and size(e_list) = num_edges.

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: row_ptr[:num_vertices + 2])
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < num_edges; i++)
        row_ptr[std::get<0>(e_list[i]) + 1]++;
```

The problem could be the available RAM of the machine or could be something else?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Arrays used in reduction are reserved on the stack. So, the most probable cause of your problem is that your stack is too small and you have an overflow. Try increasing it by setting the [OMP_STACKSIZE](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse54.html) environmental variable. If it does not solve your problem, please provide a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: windows 11 with wsl (ubuntu)

Comment: e.g. `setenv OMP_STACKSIZE 50M`

Comment: on terminal? or on code?

Comment: on terminal before you run your code

Comment: How `row_ptr` is allocated? On stack or on the heap?

Comment: setenv "command not found" so i used export OMP_STACKSIZE=50M

Comment: and it not run, return "segmentation fault"

Comment: row ptr on the heap

Comment: How big is `num_vertices`?

Comment: around 2394385 uint64_t

Comment: try `ulimit -s 90000`, if it does not help post a [mre]